# page-break-inside:avoid doesn't work if float:left is used in inner div mpdf

Tags: php, html, css, mpdf

I am trying to use `page-break-inside: avoid` style for outer div which has multiple div with `float:left` style in it. But it doesn't work and shows everything jumbled up. But if I don't use `float:left` in inner div, the page break works perfectly. Any solution for this?

Comment: please provide a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)